# Htmx-functionality inside dynamically loaded elements, Initialize htmx on Dynamically Loaded Elements via Custom JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, htmx

after dynamically loading elements with htmx properties the htmx function don't seem to be activated on the dynamically loaded alements. It's important to know that the dynamically loaded alements are being loaded with custom js and not via htmx, but it needs to work anyways.
Or in other words: how can I make htmx be aware of newly added html loaded with non-htmx ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like i already found an answer. *htmx.process* does the magic.
Example using a jquery callback function:

```
$('#mydiv').load( url2load , function() {
        if (typeof htmx !== "undefined") { 
            htmx.process(document.getElementById('mydiv'));
        }
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

Silly question ... But you are using jQuery to ajax load content. But have htmx, which is a library to load Ajax content, aswell?

My solution would be

```
<div id="mydiv" hx-get="url" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="this">
```

Comment: People might wanna integrate htmx with existing code gradually... and existing code might use other methods to load content since it is not (yet) aware that htmx exists.